# I'm getting so many errors in my unity 2d movement script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I wrote a movement script and it wasn't working and I had many errors. I'm new so I don't know how to read the errors and I don't have any coding friends.
I had 9 errors and did research before. There was something called forcemode that I did overlook that might have to be used.

These were my errors:

*Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(36,27): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(33,27): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(30,27): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(17,39): error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'PlayerMovement.ForceD2'

Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(17,33): error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'PlayerMovement.Force'

Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(16,27): error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'PlayerMovement.Force'

Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(36,30): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'UnityEngine.ForceMode2D'

Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(39,27): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(39,30): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'UnityEngine.ForceMode2D'*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //rb2D is assigned to the selected rigid body
    public Rigidbody2D rb2D;


    void Awake(){
        rb2D = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    //Lets you remotely change the amount of force being put on the object 
    public int Force;
    private int ForceD2 = Force*2f;
    private int NegitiveForce = Force-ForceD2;

    //Allows you to remotely turn off keys
    public bool left;
    public bool right;
    public bool down;
    public bool up;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Moves Object Based on Key

        if(Input.GetKey("a")|| Input.GetKey("left") && left){
            rb2D.AddForce(NegitiveForce,0f);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("d")|| Input.GetKey("right") && right){
            rb2D.AddForce(Force,0f);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("s")|| Input.GetKey("down") && down){
            rb2D.AddForce(0f,NegitiveForce);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("w")|| Input.GetKey("up") && up){
            rb2D.AddForce(0f,Force);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is of course in `c#`

Answer (score 2):

So to the first

> Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(16,27): error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'PlayerMovement.Force'

this is caused by

```
public int Force;
private int ForceD2 = Force*2f;
private int NegitiveForce = Force-ForceD2;
```

and telling you, you can't simply access the `Force` and later `Force2D` at this point. You rather need to shift this into e.g.

```
public int Force;
private int ForceD2;
private int NegitiveForce;

pivate void Awake()
{
    ForceD2 = Force * 2f;
    NegitiveForce = Force - ForceD2;
}
```

or if you want to keep these updating on runtime you could use properties like e.g.

```
public int Force;
private int ForceD2 => Force*2f;
private int NegitiveForce => Force-ForceD2;
```

which means they will be recalculated for each and every access.

*Besides that,why is `NegitiveForce` not rather simply `-Force` ..?*

---

And then to

> Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(36,30): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'UnityEngine.ForceMode2D'

and

> Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(39,27): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Then other than for [`Rigidbody.AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) where there is an overload taking `float, float, float` is parameters, **there is no such overload for [`Rigidbody2D.AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html)!**

The only overload here is

```
public void AddForce(Vector2 force, ForceMode2D mode = ForceMode2D.Force);
```

and the compiler is telling you that your input parameters are not compatible with it ;)